# Convert GPGSV to GPRMC or to Google map location?

Tags: nmea

Currently I am using U-Blox 7m GPS with Arduino, on run time, it is giving value on Serial Monitor like:

```
$GPRMC,204843.00,V,,,,,,,151019,,,N*79
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,204843.00,,,,,0,03,11.41,,,,,,*69
$GPGSA,A,1,28,30,07,,,,,,,,,,11.46,11.41,1.00*08
$GPGSV,3,1,12,01,16,047,,02,02,199,,04,01,168,,06,31,170,*74
$GPGSV,3,2,12,07,20,136,24,11,11,042,,13,41,260,,15,18,290,09*76
$GPGSV,3,3,12,17,75,340,,19,69,256,,28,46,029,20,30,53,130,22*79
$GPGLL,,,,,204843.00,V,N*43
```

it's about an hour, and its continuously giving this value, how do I convert $GPGSV value to google map location???

Answer (score 1):

`$GPRMC` will give you the data you want.  A typical sentence looks like this:

```
$GPRMC,225446,A,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,000.5,054.7,191194,020.3,E*68
```

In that example, the coordinates are 49 deg 16.45 min North, 123 deg 11.12 min West.  (Example from:  http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rmc)

In your data however, you don't have a good enough signal to get a fix.  That's why you're not seeing coordinates in your data.

Comment: that's helpful but I ask to convert GPGSV to GPRMC or how to extract Latitude and Longitude from GPGSV???

Comment: @MubashirAyub You can't from the data you show because there is no GPS fix.